# SQL Error (1064) syntax MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I can't figure this out for the life of me. I have the following SQL statement which I run and it tells me the error is on the `ORDER BY d GROUP BY d;` line

```
SELECT d, SUM(e) AS Se, SUM(q) AS Sq
FROM table1
WHERE code <> '1b'
AND sDate BETWEEN #2016/08/10# AND #2016/08/17#
ORDER BY d GROUP BY d;
```

This code works in MS Access 2013 because I have the same table there. In this case I am using MariaDB, basically the same as MySQL, so I'm not sure if there are any syntax changes that I am missing.

Thanks

**Solved**

After trying things out I got it working. For some reason it does not like the # signs, so I switched them all to apostrophes. I also switched the order of the GROUP BY d and ORDER BY d.

```
SELECT d, SUM(e) AS Se, SUM(q) AS Sq
FROM table1
WHERE Code <> '1b'
AND sDate BETWEEN '2016-08-10' AND '2016-08-17'
GROUP BY d
ORDER BY d;
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` must come after `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Uueerdo I updated my question and posted the solution

Comment: Do your "weeks" have 8 days?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
SELECT d, SUM(e) AS Se, SUM(q) AS Sq
FROM table1
WHERE code <> '1b' AND Code <> '2b'
AND sDate BETWEEN #2016/08/10# AND #2016/08/17#
GROUP BY d ORDER BY d ;
```

Comment: The group by and order by was only half the problem. I showed the solution in my question